# Azure rest api equivalent to az sql db show-connection-string -s myserver -n mydb -c ado.net

Tags: azure, rest, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database, command-line-interface

I am unable to find rest api call equivalent to az sql db show-connection-string -s myserver -n mydb -c ado.net. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, we just need to append `--debug` parameter to the CLI command to see the REST API the command calls.
For this command, we can easily find it does not call any REST API via the `--debug` parameter, it just does a splicing of the parameters you input, because the format of the connection string is static.

[image]

Reference - https://www.connectionstrings.com/azure-sql-database/

Comment: Thanks Joy . So you mean it always form connection string by appending .database.windows.net & default port number .